# Play Sound in slient mode at callee end that can be listen to caller end

Tags: android, audio

There are two android mobile devices A & B. Suppose A is calling to B. At end of B, call automatically received. And a audio is played at end of B. That will be listen to A. 
For this speaker of B should be ON. So that sound of audio can be passed through MIC of B.
I want same scenario but at end of B, audio should not be audible. i.e. is there any way by which audio at A can be listen but no sound should be there at end of B.

Comment: No. Android apps can't inject audio into the voice call uplink.